# Industry stats for number of bugs found post development / Release

Tags: release, sdlc

Is there anywhere I can find out about the IT industry stats for the number of defects found post delivery, mainly based around lines of code or function points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few sources which cover software defect studies:

- [Open Source Code Quality Report](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/open-source-code-quality-on-par-with-proprietary-code-in-2011-coverity-scan-report-140152543.html)
- [Public Utility Software Vulnerability Report](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/04/rise-of-ics-forever-day-vulnerabiliities-threaten-critical-infrastructure/)
- [Cost of Software Defects across the Industry](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/psd/13-businesscase.htm)